# How to display formatted body of an email in html - Python/Django/PostgreSQL

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql

I retrieve emails from Outlook and store them in PostgreSQL. I then display the e-mails in a .html page with Django:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block page_content %}

    {% for i in ticket %}
        <p>Requester: {{i.requester}}</p>
        <P>Subject: {{i.title}}</p>
        <p>Description: {{i.description}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The body(i.description) of the email has the format of a html xmlns file, for example:

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head>

<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)">
<style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
span.EmailStyle17
    {mso-style-type:personal-compose;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    color:windowtext;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:612.0pt 792.0pt;
    margin:72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body lang="EN-GB" link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72">
<div class="WordSection1">
<p class="MsoNormal">Testing how body works now<o:p></o:p></p>
...
```

How can I display the email with this html xmlns text format, such that it keeps the original formatting? Is there a way to embed that wall of text into html?

Expected:

[image: Expected Look]

Currently displayed:

[image: Currently displayed]

I tried `<p><embed type="text/html" src={{i.description}}></p>`

`{{i.description}}` Can be a plain text format instead, but the formatting is still destroyed when displayed on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `safe` filter:

```
{{ i.description|safe }}
```

Read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe